# FlowLayout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I needed a view as in figure below. I avoided the use of GridView because i was unable to scroll to lower parts of my app as the GridView takes almost all the screen. And scrolling would only scroll gridview and not the app in overall. Hence I created the the following layout using LinearLayout which contains ImageView and TextView for the items. The four LinearLayout itself is contained in a LinearLayout.

[image]

Now the problem is how do i make a layout which automatically adjusts to a little bigger size like in figure below.

[image]

I used various flowlayout libraries like [library1](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout) and [library2](https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout) but both of them didnot work for me because i wasn't able to scroll and my linearlayout was squished too.

Below is my code for the linear layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.test.FirstHomeActivity">




    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llFeatured1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="featuredClick1"
        android:background="@drawable/card_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="290dp"
        android:minHeight="290dp">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/featuredImg1"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_width="166dp"
            android:layout_height="264dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:textColor="#33CC33" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llFeatured2"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="featuredClick2"
        android:background="@drawable/card_layout"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="290dp"
        android:minHeight="290dp">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/featuredImg2"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_width="166dp"
            android:layout_height="264dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:textColor="#33CC33" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llFeatured3"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="featuredClick3"
        android:background="@drawable/card_layout"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="290dp"
        android:minHeight="290dp">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/featuredImg3"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_width="166dp"
            android:layout_height="264dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:textColor="#33CC33" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Any kind of example source code or any solution would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [flow layout](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout).

No need to re-invent the wheel if someone has already done it for you. :)

Comment: I cannot scroll using this library. Moreover If the height is a little bit big then all the items in new row gets overlapped with the items in first row.

Comment: You can't scroll with a LinearLayout either. You have to wrap it inside a ScrollView.